# jquery mobile views overlap

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

I am working on a project which uses backbone.js, jqmnavigator, require.js, jquerymobile and phonegap.

For some reason the app works fine in simulator but when I put the same app on the device , the views overlap after few screen transitions.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like i found the reason for overlapping views.

One of the reason was , i was doing some intensive work in side "render" call. So i think it was causing the view to overlap.

When i moved it to , "'pageshow': 'this_pageshowHandler'" this_pageshowHandler(), the overlapping of the views went off.

Also, i followed some tips from :
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/10-ways-to-instantly-increase-your-jquery-performance/